# Unable to see 'npmrc' file for node JS v6.9.5 on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I was using nodeJS v6.9.5 on Windows7 machine and modified **npmrc** file located at path -C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\ with following lines to add scope and registry URL for installing my project dependencies/ required packages. It worked well and I was able to install the packages.

```
scope=test-incubator
@test-aquila:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Now, I have installed node JS v6.9.5 on Linux machine using https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.5/node-v6.9.5-linux-x64.tar.xz
, I'm unable to see npmrc file at path - node-v6.9.5-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/

I'm unable to see and edit **npmrc** file to install my project dependencies.
Can anyone please suggest, where to get this npmrc file on node JS setup folder on Linux machine or any other alternative to add scope/registry url for npm configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question the way you have phrased it, but I would strongly recommend that you include your `.npmrc` file as a file at the root of each project. For example, your folder structure might look like this:

```
my-project
|__some-folder
|__.gitignore
|__.npmrc
|__package.json
```

Each time you update your node version, node version specific files will be lost. This also applies to globally installed npm packages, which is one of the reasons why I recommend installing npm packages locally and never globally. The other key reason for having all of the configuration local to your project is so that any other developer, or any other computer that is used to develop on your project, has the `.npmrc` file and all other configuration related to that project.